# Como colocar uma letra do lado direito da página, mostrando a primeira letra do ultimo registro?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

Como eu posso colocar uma letra do lado direito da página, mostrando a primeira letra do ultimo registro no JasperReports?

Outra coisa é que a letra precisa ser de A-Z(como uma lista telefônica).

Esse é um exemplo do que eu quero:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A primeira letra do último registro da página?

Comment: Exato, conforme a figura acima, o último registro seria a "Laura Steel" e neste caso, apresentaria a letra "L" na página. Com relação a letra eu consigo pegá-la através da substring. Porém não tenho ideia de qual componente poderia ser utilizado para apresentar desta forma.

Answer (score 0):

Olá voce pode marcar no componente o Evaluation time(Evaluation time) o componente deve exibir o dado de acordo com um tempo selecionado o valor padrão é now(Agora) mas se vc mudar Report(Relatorio) acredito que va ficar o ultimo valor , ai para pegar apenas a primeira letra basta usar a função subString(0,1) da classe String.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora para a lista ser em ordem alfabetica  eu recomendaria usar groups e mudar seu Layout um pouco para algo do tipo meu exemplo seria um layout parecido.Usei Groups para criar essa lista em niveis

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vamos ao Tutorial de como criar e usar o Groups,

1. clique com o botão direito no relatorio e selecione create group.

[image: Como Criar o group]

2. Aqui voce define o nome do grupo e decide se vai criar o grupo por uma expressao ou por um objeto no relatorio, no caso sempre uso a segunda opção e seleciono o campo que será utilizado para criar meu grupo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Aqui voce decide se ira usar Bandas no Header e no Footer( Sim cada grupo cria uma nova banda no menu do seu relatorio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4. Na imagem vemos como fica apos a inserção das bandas referente ao grupo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

5. Clicando na banda voce pode ver a expressão que a cria tal como algumas outras configurações extras para a propria banda em questão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que tenha sido util a resposta e consiga resolver seu problema. Se sim nao deixe de positivar a resposta.

Comment: Denis, obrigado pela dica. Pode me fornecer um exemplo?

Comment: Como voce quer o exemplo ? um tutorial usando o groups ?

Comment: Usando groups já ajudaria bastante. obrigado!

Comment: Ta feito meu caro veja se te ajuda